# Automatically scroll down Listbox in Tkinter app

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi guys I'm making this chat app with tkinter and it works perfectly except by the fact that the text I post in my Listbox, don't shows up the way I want. Once the space in the Listbox finishes, I have to manually scroll down to see recent messages. My question is, what can I do to make the Listbox automatically scroll down when it gets fill. This is the part of the code of the Listbox
   `lista=Listbox(raiz,font=('Arial'))
 lista.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10,ipadx=200,fill=X,expand=True )`

And this is where I posted:

```
def post(text,n=0):
   winsound.Beep(400,150)
   if n==0:
      lista.insert(END,text)
      campo.delete(0,1000)  
   else:
      for i in text:
          lista.insert(END,i)
```

If you can help me it will be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: i think the you should clear the `Listbox` and display the current one.

Comment: The listbox has a `see` method to scroll a particular item into view.

Comment: Please rename your title that emphasizes the specific issue you're having. Right now the title leads to nowhere.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley you should put your comment in an answer to mark it as correct because that was the method i used, and it works perfectly

Comment: You don't need to use `Listbox` @amh9412

Answer (score 2):

You need add this line `lista.see(tkinter.END)` before `lista.insert(END,text)`

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the `Listbox` widget before you display the current or insert

```
def post(text,n=0):
   winsound.Beep(400,150)
   if n==0:
      lista.delete(0, END) # this to clear the listbox and display the current content in the listbox
      lista.insert(END,text)
      campo.delete(0,1000)  
   else:
      for i in text:
          lista.insert(END,i)
```

Or you can place the new content at top of `Listbox` like this,

```
def post(text,n=0):
   winsound.Beep(400,150)
   if n==0:
      return
      lista.insert(n-1, text)
      campo.delete(0,1000)  
   else:
      for i in text:
          lista.insert(END,i)
```

Since you didn't post your full code or minimal am assuming this how it is.

Comment: This way I can't see a history of received messages or will I?

Comment: A comment, `n`, is just a marker if its value is 0 it means that the action triggering the function is a Button or a press key defined with `bind()`, if it is 1 it means that the action triggering the function is an incoming socket messages

Comment: i don't know what code you have at your end, create minimal code so you can get help.With this you are giving me burden .

Comment: I find a way to automatically scroll down the `Listbox` always a text is posted. The way I do it is with `lista.see(END)`, this way always a text is inserted with  `lista.insert(END,text)`, the listbox automatically will show the END that is where the new text is.